# "Cannot be cast to java.lang.Class", namely: which type is not a class

Tags: java, introspection

This may seem a dumb question (as it could be very project specific) but in this case it's general enough:

I'm running a piece of code which gives the `ClassCastException`, with the error message I wrote as title. Here the mentioned cast is from an object of type `java.lang.reflect.Type` to `Class<?>`.

Apart from primitive types, which type in Java is not a class?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please post the line of code and original error

Comment: All of them. `Class` is itself a class that inherits from `Object`, so the usual rules apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Class` is a `Type` but a `Type` isn't necessary a `Class`, since [`Class` implements `Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Basically, your `myType` could also be any of the implementing classes of the interfaces [`GenericArrayType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericArrayType.html), [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html), [`TypeVariable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) or [`WildcardType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/WildcardType.html), since they all extend the [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) interface.

Try to print `myType.getClass()` to see the type you mean: you'll get `Class<TheSaidType>`.

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for [Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) you can see it has a number of implementing types.

```
All Known Subinterfaces:
    GenericArrayType, ParameterizedType, TypeVariable<D>, WildcardType

All Known Implementing Classes:
    Class
```

Th sub-interfaces are implemented using internal data structure classes.